# Storing credit card numbers with Paypal's Website Payments Pro

Tags: paypal, payment, credit-card, recurring-billing

We currently use the Website Payments Pro recurring billing solution from Paypal for a SaaS web application (user signs up for a monthly billing subscription to our service) but are becoming increasingly concerned that all of our credit card data is 'locked in' to Paypal and we can never get access to it.

The ideal for us is at the point of signup to store a users credit card details in a third party system (vault) whilst processing the transaction through Paypal's Website Payments Pro billing solution.  This would give us the freedom to change our payment processor without having to ask everyone of our users to re-enter their card details - storing payment details in a third party PCI compliant system would allow us to do this.

Does anyone know of any such solutions that would allow us to store credit card details without transacting against them and whether these would be available to UK based companies ?

Thanks - appreciate any help you can give.

Mike

Answer (score 3):

PayPal now offers such a service

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#vault

Answer (score 2):

I found that Briantree.com offers that service

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that does this (but would love to hear otherwise). The reason it doesn't exist I would assume is because 'my' PCI-DSS requires that any third party that I pass card details to is also PCI compliant.

Therefore, this 'vault' provider would only be able to return to you a full card number if *you* were fully PCI compliant (and if you were, then why would you need to use a 3rd party vault?!)

So the best you could optimistically hope for is a 3rd party that both vaults the details and also allows interaction with 'n' other payment gateways, but this would obviously only allow you to switch between gateways that the vault supports. Given that the 'vault' would need to generate income, as well as the gateways that it communicates with, I can't see this being cheaper than choosing and interacting with a single gateway directly.